# Multiple x,y,z values - is there a way to write them in short?

Tags: python, matplotlib, line-plot, matplotlib-3d

!!! >> I'm a total newbie, I opened matplotlib like 3 hours ago and self-taught myself here. If you introduce any new commands/lines, please let me know what they're called so I can look up tutorials, thanks!

Attempting to: Make a 3d plot of tracks/lines

Problem: I have a .csv files with **29 sets of x y z data points with 49 rows (time points). i.e. I'm tracking 29 particles in 3d space over 49 timepoints**. The column headers ATM are "x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2 ..." etc.
The 3D part is not an issue, but I'm kind of not interested in writing out 70+ lines of the same thing.

I.e. I'd rather not write:

```
x = points['x'].values
x2 = points['x2'].values
x3 = points['x3'].values
...
x29 = points['x29'].values
```

etc.

Is there a way to say "plot x1,y1,z1 to x29,y29,z29 from that .csv" instead?

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import numpy as np

points = pandas.read_csv('D:Documents\PYTHON_FILES/test3d.csv')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

x = points['x'].values
y = points['y'].values
z = points['z'].values

x2 = points['x2'].values
y2 = points['y2'].values
z2 = points['z2'].values


ax.plot(x, y, z, c='red', marker='o', linewidth=1.0, markersize=2)
ax.plot(x2, y2, z2, c='blue', marker='o', linewidth=1.0, markersize=2)


plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, based on your code who have things labelled as `x`, `x2` and so on...
So, the logic is:

1. Use a for loop to iterate over numbers
2. Use f-strings to make things easier.

Here's the code:

```
for i in range(1, 30):
    if i == 1: i = '' #x is your first value not x1
    ax.plot(points[f"x{i}"], points[f"y{i}"], points[f"z{i}"], c='red', marker='o', linewidth=1.0, markersize=2)
```

F-strings are basically strings but with variables.
You can write `f` before a string and use `{}` brackets to add variables.
Note, both of them give the same output:

```
a = "!"
print("Hello"+a)
print(f"Hello{a}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a fixed number of rows you can iterate over a range to get values.  If it weren't fixed, you could count rows and use that to set the range.

```py
for idx in range(29):
   suffix = '' if idx == 0 else str(idx + 1) # ranges start at 0
   x = points[f"x{suffix}"].values 
   y = points[f"y{suffix}"].values
   z = points[f"z{suffix}"].values

   ax.plot(x, y, z, c='red', marker='o', linewidth=1.0, markersize=2)

plt.show()
```

UPDATE:
responding to @TheMyth's comments

Comment: The code won't work. Their first value is `x` not `x1`. Secondly, they want only 29 numbers not 49. You could also start the range from `1` rather than increasing every value by `1`

Comment: good catch on the first value

Comment: That's a point of consideration somehow.

Comment: Thank you so much too! I realise my first x/y/z numbers are a bit messy, but columns can easily be changed anyways + the code worked also!